# making a joke about something being "haram" when it's not does that take you out of Islam?

Tags: halal-haram

I was with my friend in our schools assembly the national anthem started playing and he jokingly said I am American so I can't sing this national anthem who ch was playing(it was Pakistani national anthem) so I with a serious face and joking manner said this is haram I never mean to insult elements of islam please help

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, joking should never involve mockery of Islam, as it can lead to serious consequences regarding one's faith. This sentiment is echoed in the Quran, where Allah admonishes those who mock His signs and His Messenger. Ibn Taymiyah further elucidates that such mockery constitutes disbelief, leading one astray from their faith.

Similarly, jesting about certain Sunnah practices, such as the beard, hijab, or garment length, is equally problematic. Shaykh Muhammad ibn ‘Uthaymin emphasizes the sanctity of matters pertaining to Divine Lordship, Prophethood, Revelation, and religion, stating that disrespecting them, whether through mockery or jest, is tantamount to disrespecting Allah and His teachings. Such actions demand repentance, seeking forgiveness, and a genuine commitment to revering Allah and His commandments.

You're fine in-sha-Allah, avoid it, though, before it's turned into a habit.

For more on the topic, see:
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/22170/what-are-the-conditions-of-joking-in-islam

---

P.s. Consider using punctuation when writing, it would help others understand your post more easily.